# ASP .NET - Retrieve values from selected Listview control row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

My Listview control contains 4 columns and 30 rows.
I can retrieve the row number by using:

```
//get row of listview item
ListViewDataItem item1 = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
int findMe = item1.DisplayIndex;
```

How do I then get values from one or all 4 columns?

I was trying:

```
this.lblReponseRoute.Text = item1.FindControl("routenameLabel").ID.ToString();
```

**UPDATE1:**

The final solution is:

```
//get row of listview item
ListViewDataItem item1 = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
int findMe = item1.DisplayIndex;

//find label value
var routeLabel = (Label)ListView1.Items[findMe].FindControl("routenameLabel");
this.lblReponseRoute.Text = routeLabel.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `routenameLabel` is a server control, I believe you're going to have to cast it as such prior to accessing the properties:

```
var routeLabel = (Label)item1.FindControl("routenameLabel");
lblResponseRoute.Text = routeLabel.ID.ToString();
```

Do you get an error on the code you've posted?

**Edit:** Note that in your *real* code you'd want to test for null before casting to the Label.

Comment: thanks.  I wasn't getting any specific error - just the ID of the label when I want it's value.  I have edited my post with the final code solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var routeLabel = (Label)item1.FindControl("routenameLabel"); 
lblResponseRoute.Text = routeLabel.ID.ToString();
```

It should be:

```
var routeLabel = (Label)item1.FindControl("routenameLabel"); 
lblResponseRoute.Text = routeLabel.Text.ToString();
```

`.Text` not `.ID`, we already know the name of the label.